# Trying to redirect from non SSL certificated sites to SSL certificated sites

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate, redirect

I bought a SSL certificate for the domain *https://www.mypage.com*. I have other domains like *https://www.mypage.fr*, *https://www.mypage.es*...For those I didn't buy a SSL certificate.

When I go to *https://www.mypage.com* the page is showed directly OK, but if I go to *https://www.mypage.fr*, the browser shows the typical message "This Connection is Untrusted"..

When the user enter to *https://www.mypage.fr* I would like to redirect the user to *https://www.mypage.com* in order to not showing the message "This connection is untrusted..".

For that, I have written this in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mypage.com [NC] 
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.mypage.com [R=301,L]
```

but when I go to *https://www.mypage.fr* the browser still shows the message "This connection is untrusted...".

So what should I do to redirect my sites avoiding this message?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give them an SSL certificate. Unfortunately, in order to open the connection and get the redirect information from the server, the browser and web server first have to establish an HTTP/SSL connection, which of course involves presenting the assigned certificate. There isn't really any way around this that I know of. At the very least, assign the "www.mypage.com" certificate to the other domain names, and that way it's at least evident that they're legitimate.